# Dynamic Row Level Security for Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to allow users privileges by region with PBI DAX expression implementation to first get USERPRINCIPALNAME then proceed to get their region.

User Table:

[image]

Scenario:
When Shaun login to powerBI service. He only can view the dashboard and dataset in region R10.

Comment: How your user table related to your data table?

Comment: Hi mkRabbani, I had solved the problem using filter and selectcolumn function. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple tables you want to control with dynamic security, you might prefer an approach based on the propagation of the security filters through the relationships instead of using a DAX expression for every table you want to filter.

What we have to do is to create a new role and use this code to apply security filter for the user table :

```
[EMAIL]= USERPRINCIPALNAME()
```

The second thing to do is to apply bi-directionnal filtering for the relationship betwen user_region and region.

Comment: Hi BOUBRIT Nacim, I had solved the problem using filter and selectcolumn function. Thanks man.